# Issue fix for kernel update

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, linux-kernel, inspect

I ran the **AWS Inspector** on an Ubuntu **14.04** instance (**kernel 3.13.0**), a lot of issues found and most of them recommends a kernel update. However, according to the description of the issues, some issue exists through the kernel  4.13.11

How I can fix these issue?

Example issue:

**ARN** arn:aws:inspector:us-east-1:459822950501:target/0-wPJLYMUo/template/0-MOs0F6Sk/run/0-1S1WNiwa/finding/0-29BA4zLm

**Run name** Run - INTELLI_AUDIO_LINUX - 2018-05-16T13:07:05.484Z
**Target name** INTELLI_LINUX_AUDIO

**Template name** INTELLI_AUDIO_LINUX

**Start** Yesterday at 4:07 PM (GMT+3) (a day ago)

**End** Yesterday at 4:23 PM (GMT+3) (a day ago)
**Status** Analysis complete
**Rules package** Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures-1.1
**AWS agent ID i-**d53***
Finding Instance i-d533bf52 is vulnerable to CVE-2016-1583

**Severity** High

**Description** 
The ecryptfs_privileged_open function in fs/ecryptfs/kthread.c in the Linux kernel before 4.6.3 allows local users to gain privileges or cause a denial of service (stack memory consumption) via vectors involving crafted mmap calls for /proc pathnames, leading to recursive pagefault handling.

**Recommendation** 
Use your Operating System's update feature to update package linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic-0:3.13.0-48.80. For more information see https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-1583

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your kernel to a version greater then 4.13.11. [CVE-2016-1583](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-1583) is fixed after kernel 4.6.3 . These issues are security issues in your kernel. And they have high severity! The only way to fix them, is to change the kernel you are using.
If you are missing newest kernel in your packages repository (ubuntu 14.04 does not have the newest version), then [dist-upgrade](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts) your system thus upgrade your kernel.